# Lashon Harah between two separate parties

Tags: halacha, lashon-hara-slander

Is it Lashon Harah if I am speaking true, non-condemning facts about a person to someone who has no idea who I'm talking about? (i.e I don't say their name and they wouldn't know who it was anyway, or I say 'my parents' to people who don't know/will never know my parents).
Sometimes I want to talk about things that are bothering me or even that I'm only thinking a lot about, and other people might be able to offer some insight.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Gabe and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Answer (score 2):

1] non-condemning facts
From [What is Lashon Hara? Torah.org](https://torah.org/learning/halashon-review1/)

> Lashon Hara is any derogatory or damaging statement against an
> individual. Rambam says, “Anything which, if it would be publicized,
> would cause the subject physical or monetary damage, or would cause
> him anguish or fear, is Lashon Hara.”

so non-condemning facts  are not Lashon Hara.

2] about a person to someone who has no idea who I'm talking about
From  [Chofetz Chaim: Ethics of Speech, Torah.org](https://torah.org/learning/halashon-chapter3/)

> The prohibition against speaking Lashon Hara applies even if, at the
> time of the conversation, the speaker does not identify the subject
> about whom he is speaking against.  Even if the speaker only relates
> the story without mentioning the parties involved, yet from the
> details of the story the listener discerns which person the speaker
> refers to, the information is Lashon Hara.

If the hearer would **never** have an idea who you are talking about it is not Lashon Hara.

3] Sometimes I want to talk about things that are bothering me or even that I'm only thinking a lot about, and other people might be able to offer some insight.

From [Laws of Lashon Hara While Venting, Chabad Info, Rabbi Y Y Braun](https://chabadinfo.com/beis-medrash/laws-of-lashon-hara-while-venting/)

> If necessary, one may vent about an insult etc. and include the
> person’s name, provided one meets the following conditions:
>
> 1. The objective is only to vent so that you feel better and nothing else. The venting is what makes makes you feel better and not putting
>    someone else down.
> 2. Speaking directly to the person who insulted you etc. would not be productive.
> 3. You do not have any other options to make yourself feel better.
> 4. You are talking about something that you experienced directly and not that you heard from someone else.
> 5. Before talking to someone else you must first reexamine the scenario calmly to determine if you are truly in the right and the
>    other person’s action was unwarranted etc.
> 6. You may only tell one person.
> 7. There won’t be a significant negative fallout to the person who insulted you.
> 8. You may not exaggerate and you may not leave out details that would show the other side in a more positive light.

So to relieve your tension, this might be permissible.

Comment: I'm not sure Din Online is a reliable resource. Who wrote and reviewed that article?

Comment: Thank you. What is worrying is that no author or reviewer is named. On the other hand, this is indeed the halacha as I remember it. Moreover this site https://dinonline.org/the-kollel/ describes the set up of the various activities of the organisation. If I have time, I will try and source this aspect elsewhere.

Comment: @N.T. I have edited the answer using a reliable source.

Comment: That seems more reasonable. For the record I don't consider Chabad a reliable resource.